# Make __init__ variables into attributes automatically

Tags: python, class, variables, attributes

I have a class as follows:

```
class Sample:

    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3, ...):

        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        self.var3 = var3
        ...
```

except I have more than 10 variables which I want to be attributes that can be changed when calling the class. It seems overly verbose. Is there some way to abbreviate this? I am envisioning something as concise as

```
class Sample:

    def __init__(self, *var1, *var2, var3, ...):

        ...
```

and then the variables `var1` and `var2` would automatically become attributes `self.var1`, `self.var2`. Is there anything like this, or do I need to do this like in the first block of code above?

Comment: You can use a dataclass.

Answer (score 0):

You class might be doing more than one thing (not good OO), or the attributes are to be treated uniformly. In this case you can explicitly use a dictionary:

```
class Sample:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.data = dict(kwargs)
```

Or a dataclass, if you care about names validation, as suggested in the comments:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Sample:
    var1: str
    var2: float
    ...
```

Comment: "Or a dataclass, if you care about names and type validation" dataclasses do not do any type validation

Answer (score 0):

There's always Martelli's classic *Python Cookbook* recipe:

```
class Bunch:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)


foo = Bunch(a=13, b=42)
print(f'{foo.a=}') # -> foo.a=13
print(f'{foo.b=}') # -> foo.b=42
```

Nowadays, [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-dataclasses) would be the better way to go.

Suggest you watch Raymond Hettinger's [Dataclasses: The code generator to end all code generators](https://youtu.be/T-TwcmT6Rcw) talk on youtube.